# Create a list of items that are checked after form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 4 here and I have a page of a list of activities that are generated from an XML file. More than 1 activity can be checked and within each activity the user can set the date, the number of adults/children. My plan is when the user clicks submit, all the activities that were checked are put into a list of ActivityItems. Here is what I defined an ActivityItem as:

**ActivityItem Class**

```
public class ActivityItem
{
    public string ActivityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int NumAdults { get; set; }
    public int NumChildren { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

My View looks like this (I took out a lot of styling and formatting to make the code easier to read). Please note that the @item.ActivityID starts at "ACT001" then "ACT002" and then "ACT003" and so on until n times.

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Activity>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="activity" id="@item.ActivityID">
            <h3>@item.Name</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" id="@item.ActivityID-Check" name="checkbox"/>  

        <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Date:</label>
        <select name="select-choice-0" id="@item.ActivityID-Date">
            <option value="07/03/2012">07/03/2012</option>
            <option value="07/04/2012">07/04/2012</option>
            <option value="07/05/2012">07/05/2012</option>
            <option value="07/06/2012">07/06/2012</option>
        </select>   

        @Html.DropDownList(item.ActivityID+"-AdultNum", AdultNum)<br />
        Price/Adult C$:@Html.TextBox(item.ActivityID+"-AdultPrice", item.PricePerAdult)

        @Html.DropDownList(item.ActivityID+"-ChildNum", ChildNum)<br /> 
        Price/Child C$: @Html.TextBox(item.ActivityID+"-ChildPrice", item.PricePerChild)

        <label style="color:Blue"><h3>Total Price C$:</h3></label>
        <input type="text" id="@item.ActivityID-Sum" readonly="readonly"/>

        </div> 
    </li>
}
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

So, basically if the checkbox of a particular item (@item.ActivityID-Check) is clicked and the form is submitted:

An ActivityItem will be created with the following fields filled from the activity in the list:

- List item
- ActivityID = @item.ActivityID
- Name = @item.Name
- Date = @item.ActivityID-Date
- NumAdults = @item.ActivityID-AdultNum
- NumChildren = @item.ActivityID-ChildNum
- TotalPrice = @item.ActivityID-Sum

However multiple items can be clicked and when the form is submitted, I need to return a list of ActivityItems. I have a feeling this is a complicated answer and as a result, I don't expect a full solution (Although that would be awesome haha). However, it would be a great help if I could get a few tips and pointers. I really appreciate all the advice.

Comment: If you are finding for how to bind a list, takew a look at this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I still haven't gotten it yet, but now its a little bit clearer to me.

Comment: I updated the answer you can check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to model bind a collection the first thing is the generated names of the input elements should follow a pattern.

Ex.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Author)
}
```

Note that you should replace `foreach` with `for` and this will generate a html form as below,

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">    
    <input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />

    <input type="text" name="[1].Title" value="Code Complete" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].Author" value="Steve McConnell" />

    ...
</form>
```

The next thing in your case is you have to bind only the selected items to the collection. So you have to do couple of things, 1. Remove the html elements that are not selected 2. Reset the names of the input elements and these two things you have do in the form submit event.

```
$("form").submit(function() {

   // iterate the the activities and remove the ones that are not selected 
   // ex.
   $(this).children('[0].Title').remove();
   $(this).children('[0].Author').remove();

   // again iterate the activities in the form and reset their index values
   // ex.
   $(this).children('[1].Title').attr('name', [0].Title);
   $(this).children('[1].Author').attr('name', [0].Author);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Another solution would be you can create a view model that wraps the `ActivityItem` and a boolean flag saying that whether the particular activity is selected by the user or not. From the post action you can filter the selected activities by the user. View models are helpful in this kind of scenarios and by this you can avoid listening to the form submit event.

```
public class ActivityItemViewModel
{
   public class ActivityItem { get; set; }
   public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

The view has to be binded to `IEnumerable<Project.Models.ActivityItemViewModel>` instead of `IEnumerable<Project.Models.Activity>`. The checkbox that is used for selecting the activity has to binded to the `IsSelected` property.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Isselected)
```

You will have a controller action that takes this collection as input,

```
public ActionResult PostAction(IEnumerable<Project.Models.ActivityItemViewModel>)
{
    .. now you can easily filter the Activities that are selected by checking the
    .. IsSelected boolean flag
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So after I submit the form, it returns a list of the activities that were checked right?

Comment: In this case, you have to add an array of your viewmodelk as a parameter in your action. something like: [HttpPost] public ActionResult Save(ActivityItem[] item) { /* persistence here ...*/ }

Comment: Is there a way I can PM either of you guys? I think I'm way over my head here.

Comment: *So after I submit the form, it returns a list of the activities that were checked right?* basically the idea is remove the html elements that don't needs to be submitted and reset their names in the ascending order so the model binding for the collection happen properly. I'll update the answer soon to make it more clear meanwhile can you post the action code?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use the logic from your updated solution to help me solve my problem. Many Thanks!